# How to get 2nd highest from table?

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

```
id  | name | class | marks 
 1  | abc  |  1    | 90
 2  | cdf  |  1    | 100  
 3  | xyz  |  1    | 70
```

I want to get 2nd highest marks record. How can I get it with with one query. Simple and short?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `tableName` ORDER BY `marks` DESC LIMIT 1,1
```

Comment: LIMIT 1,1 means start at record 1 (2nd record, first being 0) and return 1 record only. LIMIT 5,3 would start at 5 (actually the 6th record) and return 3.

Comment: Yes sir/ma'am. Of course if you're using PHP you can get all the results and then pull out the ones you want, instead of querying the database multiple times for one row each time.

Comment: Not ma'am here. And also single :)

Answer (score 4):

Use `LIMIT` and `ORDER`

```
SELECT * FROM table
ORDER BY marks DESC LIMIT 1,1
```

ORDER BY marks DESC means: descending ordering, so highest on top.
LIMIT 1,1 means offset = 1 and only select 1 row.